# How to add rating stars in windows application?

Tags: xaml, windows

i am developing a windows application which allow users to rate a specific picture.i want to add rating stars for this purpose.can someone help me in finding out how to add rating stars in my app.

Answer (score 0):

If if were me, i would create a user control that has images of how ever many star ratings you are wanting to use. Then when a user clicks on one of the stars, a Property such as int can be set depending on which star was clicked. Based on that, you can fill in the stars with say a yellow color. You could even utilize hover events to fill in the stars before a user clicks on one. use the Property that was created and do any type of calculations you wish to show. If you are wanting to do any type of binding to the Property, make sure you make it a dependency Property. Also, a little more information or code would be helpful in trying to help you. If you specify your question a little more or show some existing code you have written I can give you some more specifics on how you can achieve this.